# python - 2d interpolation, one dimension at a time

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to implement some interpolation techniques - specifically using the scipy pchip routine.

What I am trying to determine is whether I can perform interpolation of regularly space 2d data by interpolating each coordinate separately.

For example, if I have:

```
(1 x m) vector of X coordinates
(1 x n) vector of Y coordinates

(m x n) matrix of Z coordinates //Z value corresponding to (x,y) pair
```

Is it possible to perform pchip interpolation over each dimension in succession, therefore creating an interpolated surface?

Pchip expects data in the form of pchip(X,Z) - where both X and Z are 1D arrays.  What then is the best way to interpolate each dimension?  Should I do, for example, pchip(X,Z) for each column of my Z matrix?  Then pchip(Y,Z*) over each row of the matrix resulting from the first interpolation?

Thank you for the help.  I have seen pv post about performing tensor rpoduct interpolation with pchip, but it results in a pesky divide by zero error I can't get rid of, even with his updates on github.

**EDIT:**

I found this ticket posted regarding the warning I have using pchip:
http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1838

Could anyone please tell me what it means when it says
"The infs/nans so generated are filtered out by applying a boolean condition mask, but the mask could be applied before division to avoid the warnings altogether. "

How do I got about applying this to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the top picture in
[Bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation).
Find the rows y1, y2 nearest y,
`pchip` x in those to get R1 R2 (blue),
then linearly interpolate those to get P (green).
(You could also do that in the other order, and average the values x-then-y, y-then-x.)

However if `pchip` is nearly linear between knots (is it for your data ?),
then it would be simpler to do bilinear directly, 
either with
[scipy BivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html)
or with 
[scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html)( ... order=1 ) 
and (ahem) the wrapper
[Intergrid](http://denis-bz.github.com/docs/intergrid.html) .